# retrieve all rows from a huge table

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL. I am getting an error when I am retrieving all rows from a table. table has `78359907`(total number of records). I am querying the database through a third-party clients using `Windows DSN`. My code is working when I use

```
select * from table limit 1000000
```

but not

`select * from table limit 90000000` (this number is larger than the total number of records).

Any ideas? How to get all rows from huge tables without found rows function or Java or C++ code. I need a solution in a simple query format.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: you get all rows to show on somewhere or you need to export all to a file? if you just need to show, did you think about pagination?

Comment: I want to show/extract using another tool

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a limit.

```
SELECT * FROM table;
```

Using a simple select will retrieve all rows from that table.

Comment: I assume they're saying that if the limit just happens to be larger than the number of rows in the table, they get an error..  is that normal behaviour for MySQL?

Comment: No. When I run without limit option it gives me out of memory error. If I use limit for 5 or 10 or till 1,000,000. Query works fine. But my table has more records and limit is not working not without limit is also not working. I hope you understood?

Comment: @Jdstrong95- any other way to get all the records with limit option?

Comment: @SrinathP Well then your problem is a memory issue, not a query issue. Some clients have a 2GB limit on results display. I suggest looking in to how to output the results to a CSV file.